# Radio button and Hashmap

Tags: java, android

This is code segment i want to put the values in a Hashmap through radio button but for first time the e value inserted is null and on next click of radio button last selected option is displayed.
Here is my code Segment,Thanks ..

```
for (int i = 0; i < rgroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
     RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) rgroup.getChildAt(i);
     if (btn.getId() == checkedId) {
        String text = btn.getText().toString();
        //if ((text.compareTo("") != 0) && (text != null) ){ 
        String text1 = user_answer.put(position+"", text);                                                                                            
        Toast.makeText(context, text1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
HashMap<Integer,Boolean> map = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
Toast.makeText(context, text1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
for (int i = 0; i < rgroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
     RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) rgroup.getChildAt(i);
     if (btn.getId() == checkedId) {
         String text = btn.getText().toString();
         map.put(btn.getId(),true);
         String text1 = user_answer.put(i+"", text);
         Toast.makeText(context, text1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
}
```